# XPaths and <? ?>

Tags: xml, xpath, wix

I have a WIX file that I need to modify using MSBuild.  It starts like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
     xmlns:iis="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/IIsExtension">

  <?--... Removed Params ...-->

  <?define ProductVersion = "1.0.1"?>

  <?--... Removed Params ...-->

  <Product Id='$(var.ProductCode)'
    UpgradeCode='$(var.UpgradeCode)'
    Name='$(var.AppName)' Language="1033" Version='$(var.ProductVersion)'
    Manufacturer='$(var.Manufacturer)'>
    <Package Id='$(var.PackageCode)' InstallerVersion="200" 
    Compressed="yes" />

  <?--... Rest of the WIX XML file ...-->
```

My problem is that I don't know what the XPath would to the `<?define ProductVersion = "1.0.1"?>` would be.  Is there a way to reference that via XPath so I can use the SDC SetValue MSBuild Task to change it? It is not a node (I think) so I am not sure how to reference it.

Vaccano

Comment: I ended up using the following statement:

<Xml.ModifyFile Path="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\TestProduct.wxs"
      XPath="//processing-instruction('define')[3]"
      NewValue="ProductVersion = &quot;$(CurrentVersion)&quot;"
      ShowMatches="Yes">
    </Xml.ModifyFile>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like `/Wix/processing-instruction('define')` may work for an XPath (whether or not MSBuild recognizes that, I don't know).

By plugging that into [SketchPath](http://pgfearo.googlepages.com/), I was able to click around in it and test various XPaths to see what would select that element.

Answer (score 4):

Another approach would be to define the parameter via the command-line to candle:

```
candle -dProductVersion=1.0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

//processing-instruction('define')

Answer (score 0):

`<?define>` is a processing instruction node, so you should be able to address it using an XPath expression such as

```
//processing-instruction('define')
```